# Expect Script: Grabbing the output of a bash command and setting a variable

Tags: shell, scripting, redhat, expect, aix

I'm fairly new to expect; however, I have a current expect script that needs modifying and I'm stumped.

Here's what I'm trying to do,

host *HOSTNAME* | awk '{print $3}' | awk -v FS='.' '{print $4}' | tr -d ','

If the results are a specific number (4th octet of the IP address), then assign a variable to a specific value to be used in the script.  If it's a different value, then assign it a different variable value.

More details about what I'm trying to do with the script:
 - I have 2 different environments (both ending with specific 4th octet)
 - scp a file to the remote server (each environment has a different file)
 - connect to the system (the login prompts are also different for each environment, so would be passing different values for each environment)

*** sorry if this is confusing ***

This is what I have so far (yes, I changed some values to protect my environment).

```
spawn host hostname | awk {print \$3} | awk -v FS=. {print \$4} | tr -d ,
expect -exact 15 {
set PSWPROMPT password:
set REXPECT remotescript.exp
} -exact 10 {
set PSWPROMPT Password:
set REXPECT remotescript.exp_rh
}
send_user $PSWPROMPT $REXPECT
expect "$"
spawn scp -p filename user@hostname:PATH_FILENAME*
expect -exact "connecting (yes/no)?" {
   send  "yes\r"
   expect -exact $PSWPROMPT
   send  "filename\r"
   } -exact $PSWPROMPT {
      send  "filename\r"
   }
expect "$"
spawn scp -p filename user@hostname:PATH_FILENAME
expect -exact "connecting (yes/no)?" {
   send  "yes\r"
   expect -exact $PSWPROMPT
   send  "password\r"
   } -exact $PSWPROMPT {
      send  "password\r"
   }
expect "$"
spawn scp -p $REXPECT *username*@$hostname:PATH_FILENAME*
expect -exact "connecting (yes/no)?" {
   send  "yes\r"
   expect -exact $PSWPROMPT
   send  "password\r"
   } -exact $PSWPROMPT {
      send  "password\r"
   }
expect "$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're executing that on your local machine, and the command does not have any interactivity, just use `exec` and capture the output:

```
set output [exec host hostname | awk {{print $3}} | awk -v FS=. {{print $4}} | tr -d ,]
```

Note that curly braces in Tcl/expect act like single quotes in the shell. To pass the required braces to awk, we need to double up the braces. Or use double quotes, and escape the awk dollar sign:

```
set output [exec host hostname | awk "{print \$3}" | awk -v FS=. "{print \$4}" | tr -d ,]
```

Or we could do much of the work in expect:

```
set host_output [exec host hostname]
set first_list [lindex [split $output \n] 0]
set 3rd_word [lindex [split $first_line] 2]
set 4th_octet [lindex [split $3rd_word .] end]
set no_commas [string map {, ""} $4th_octet]
```

**OR** use a regular expression:

```
regexp {.*\.(\d+)} [exec host hostname] -> last_octet
```